# Is there a type in standard Haskell libraries implementing the following idea:

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, containers

```
data Container k = EmptyContainer| PrimContainer k (Container k) | FullContainer (Container k) (Container k) deriving (Show)

{-
*Main> let cont1 = PrimContainer 3 EmptyContainer
*Main> cont1
PrimContainer 3 EmptyContainer
*Main> let cont2 = PrimContainer 4 cont1
*Main> cont2
PrimContainer 4 (PrimContainer 3 EmptyContainer)
*Main> let cont3 = FullContainer cont1 cont2
*Main> cont3
FullContainer (PrimContainer 3 EmptyContainer) (PrimContainer 4 (PrimContainer 3 EmptyContainer))
-}
```

? Just not to reinvent the wheel.

That is, the general idea is to have a container type that can be either an empty container, a container of primitives or a container of this same type recursively

For example, it can be a set of operations, which can be treated as an operation and so on...

Comment: Exactly what would be the use of this data structure? What "problems" would it solve efficiently/elegantly?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem For example, it can be a set of operations, which can be treated as an operation and set of these operations also as one operation

Comment: This looks somewhat like a tree with optional data attached to each node. It should be equivalent to `data Container k = EmptyContainer | Node (Either k (Container k)) (Container k)`, though I don't know what purpose that kind of constrained branching would serve. Would `data Tree k = Empty | Node (Maybe k) (Container k) (Container k)` suffice? (All this to say, Haskell doesn't even have the more general `Tree` type in its standard library, let alone your more specialized version.)

Comment: @chepner something like this thanks. It seems I have to do it myself

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but I'd guess there's no such a thing in the libraries. It looks quit specific to your task rather than something general.

Comment: Hm, I might phrase this as `newtype Container k = Container [Either k (Container k)]` (same as @chepner's, but using the standard list type instead of explicit conses).